# Hide camera bounds from vieport view

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I want to screen-capture my scene animation from camera view, but can't make it fully invisible for viewer. Camera is hidden (eye icon is off). Also I've disabled passepartout darkening and checked *Only Render* in N-panel's *Display* rollout. Make things better, but thin dot-line of camera bounds is still present.

PS. I do this for the cheapest possible solution to extend camera view without distorting (need texture mask for compositing)

Comment: OpenGL render viewport doesn't show camera bounds

Comment: Problem with Open GL is that it cuts screen space as usual render, if looking from camera. But I am using animated camera